# Unity Firestore Collection Snapshot - Document Amount Returning 0

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called CalendarEvents and two documents, one named 08-01-2021 and the other named 08-02-2021. Here is my code:

```
firestore.Collection("CalendarEvents").GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {

        QuerySnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
        IEnumerable<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.Documents;

        Debug.Log("Document Amount: " + documents.ToList().Count);

    });
```

The result printed to the console is 0, and I'm not sure why because there are two documents. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Pro-tip: (If you have the choice) Please use ISO data format (YYYY-MM-DD) when using dates as filenames.  You will quickly come to appreciate sorting by name. Ref: https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the collection name is correct and contains the correct case and contains no hidden spaces `" "`.

You can also loop through the documents directly rather than store the IEnumerable to ensure that the documents are there

```js
firestore.Collection("CalendarEvents").GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
  QuerySnapshot eventsQuerySnapshot = task.Result;
  foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in eventsQuerySnapshot .Documents)
  {
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Document data for {0} document:", documentSnapshot.Id));
    Dictionary<string, object> city = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in city)
    {
      Debug.Log(String.Format("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
    }

    // Newline to separate entries
    Debug.Log("");
  }
});
```

If you still have issues, then it is most likely being blocked by Security Rules.